# Global variable for object CountDownTimer

Tags: android, kotlin

So I made a countdown timer using

```
object : CountDownTimer(waktu.toLong(), 1000)
```

Now I need to make a variable to cancel this countdowntimer like this

```
var timer = object : CountDownTimer(waktu.toLong(), 1000)
```

The problem now is I cannot access this variable from another function.
My question is how to make a global variable for this object:countdowntimer in kotlin.
I'm not sure about the variable type that I should make.
Thank you

Comment: You don't necessarily have to make it 'global'. There is more between a function's scope and the global scope. You could make it a `class variable` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use companion object to access your object from your desired location.

[for more information, you can refer to this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html#companion-objects)

**create property for timer**

```
companion object {
    lateinit var timer: CountDownTimer
}
```

**Initialize the property and start**

```
timer = object : CountDownTimer(YOUR_MAX_VALUE, 1000) {
        override fun onFinish() {
        // perform task on finish
        }
        override fun onTick(countdownTick: Long) {
        // perfrom tick event 
        }
    }.start()
```

**And cancel timer when the task is finish OR activity/fragment destroyed.**

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed()
timer.cancel()
```

}

to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @RickyGideon Just canceling the timer does not avoid memory leaks though. By initialising it as an anonymous object, it holds a reference to the enclosing class. If that is an Activity for example, that activity can never be garbage collected as long as the timer variable is around. To avoid this make it nullable and set it to null when the timer is cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin provides the `companion object` expression to deal with the global variable.

**You can do it like this.**

```
companion object {
        var timer : CountDownTimer ? = null
    }
```

**Initialize timer in your utils class or activity.**

```
timer = object : CountDownTimer(Long.MAX_VALUE, 1000) {
                                override fun onFinish() {
                                    // Cancel the timer
                                }

                                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                                    // Handle your tick event
                                }
                            }
```

**And start your timer**

```
timer?.start()
```